# Error in 2D Array Division Code?

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to look for any of the random numbers in the array and check if they are divisible by the user input. It just gives me the constant result of

> "Number of total divisible inputted numbers: (0)"

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Divisor
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[][]strings = new int [4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < strings.length;j++)
           {
               System.out.println("Please enter the 16 numbers to be checked for division!");
               strings[i][j]=keyboard.nextInt();
           }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < strings[i].length;j++)
            {
              strings[i][j] = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*100);
                if (strings[i][j]%keyboard.nextInt()==0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Number of total divisible inputted numbers: "+"("+count+")");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I'm sorry if anything isn't fitting to the normal posting rules/format since I am very new to both java and stackoverflow

Comment: Why do you read some input and completely ignore them later, and also ignore `strings` except for determining how many times to loop?

Comment: Like I have said, I am new to Java and barely understand how any of this works...:(     -I also have to get this done in like a few hours.

Comment: Edit: I added strings[i][j] = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*100); right under the second for loop. Also removed strings[i][j] = rand.nextInt();

Comment: Please apply the edit to your question.

Comment: I didn't get constant "Number of total divisible inputted numbers: (0)". http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jB4ynPor0PsnqZsg

Comment: I applied the edit, code still gives the same output

Comment: I inputted the 16 numbers into my code but it just printed out a blank page for me, once I typed in a 17th number it just said I had 0 inputted like stated above

Comment: Please tell me more detailed specification of what you want to create, so that I may be able to correct your code.

Comment: a program that creates:
 An array of random numbers between 1 and 100, and allows the user to find how many numbers in the array are divisible by an input number.

Comment: How many input do you want?

Comment: Have the user input 16 numbers because of a 4x4 array

Comment: Oh I read it incredibly wrong, its ONE INPUT NUMBER comparing to SIXTEEN NUMBERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what your code is doing? Here is a short description:

1. Make the user input 16 numbers in a array.

> ```
>   System.out.println("Please enter the 16 numbers to be checked for division!");
>       strings[i][j]=keyboard.nextInt();
> ```

2. Overwrite each number with a random int by Random.nextInt().

> ```
>     strings[i][j] = rand.nextInt();
> ```

3. Compare if a new randomized number (not the same) is divisible by a number the user inputs.

> ```
> if (rand.nextInt()%keyboard.nextInt()==0)
> ```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: I know it's all messed up... I am just so tired and have been confused on it for at least 3 days and its due very soon and I cant solve it at all.

Comment: Q. Are you suppose to compare **one** number vs the 16 in the array? Or 16 numbers vs 16 other random numbers?

Comment: One number to 16 random between 1-100 in the array! I had read it wrong and was giving slightly false directions to the other person helping me find the answer

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Divisor
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[][]strings = new int [4][4];
        int input = 0;

        // ask the user for input
       System.out.println("Please enter the 16 numbers to be checked for division!");
       input=keyboard.nextInt();

        // generate random numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < strings[i].length;j++)
            {
                strings[i][j] = 1 + rand.nextInt(100);
                //System.out.println(strings[i][j]); // print what is created for testing
            }
        }

        // count divisible numbers for each input
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < strings[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (input != 0 && strings[i][j] % input == 0) count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of total divisible inputted numbers: "+"("+count+")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both so much! This has helped immensely!

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class Divisor
    {
        public static void main (String []args)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random rand = new Random();

            int[][]strings = new int [4][4];  //Strange calling an array of ints for "strings".

            for (int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < strings[i].length;j++)
                {
                    strings[i][j] = rand.nextInt();     // Lets add some random number to a 4x4 array.
                }
            }

            int count = 0;
            int comparable = keyboard.nextInt();       // We are looking for this number.

            for (int i = 0; i < strings.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < strings[i].length;j++)
                {

                    if (strings[i][j] % comparable == 0)     //Does the number match the one we are looking for?
                    {
                        count++;
                        System.out.println("Found a number!");
                    }

                }

            }
            //We have now looked in the entire array
            System.out.println("Number of total divisible inputted numbers: "+"("+count+")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < strings.length;j++)` should be `for(int j = 0; j < strings[i].length;j++)`

Comment: You are not checking if they are divisible by the user input.

Comment: Correct and Correct. Fixed now.

Comment: Now how do I utilize the user input and random numbers between 1-100 in the array and figure out if my number divides into those random 16 numbers?

Comment: By using the % (modulus) operator to get if there is any remainder on the division.